# Xpath all text before 4th br tag

Tags: xpath

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
here a long text1 ...
<br>
<br>
here some more text2 ...
<br>
<br>
Here also text3 ..
<br>
<br>
Here text4 and so forth
</div>
```

I only want the text before the 4th br tag and maybe also the br tags itself. Like this:

```
here a long text1 ...
<br>
<br>
here some more text2 ...
<br>
<br>
```

What is the correct xpath for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With elements *and* text nodes:

```
/div/node()[count(preceding-sibling::br) < 5]
```

With text nodes only:

```
/div/text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) < 5]
```

In any case you will get a few empty text nodes with both expressions - the ones between the `<br>` elements.

Comment: Nice. How could i also include text in the A tag without having the link itself?

Comment: For example if there would be an A tag included in "here a long text1".

Comment: @Geveze The first expression will return the hypothetical `<a>` element. My recommendation would be: Just deal with it appropriately afterwards instead of trying to make a complicated XPath expression.